# How to wire dependencies in Spring tests

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I'm having a hard  time figuring out how to write Unit tests in Spring.

This is the method I'm trying to test:

```
@Service
public class ActionRequestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private Vertx vertx;

    @Autowired
    private InventoryService inventoryService;

    @Autowired
    private RequestSerializationWrapper requestWrapper;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producer;

    @EventListener
    @Transactional
    public void registerConsumer(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

        eb.consumer("bos.admin.wui.action", (Message<String> msg) -> {
            handleIncomingRequest(msg);
        });
    }
    // ...
}
```

So far I have tried creating a configuration inside my test class, like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ActionRequestHandlerTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public Vertx vertx() {
            return Mockito.mock(Vertx.class);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public InventoryService inventoryService() {
            return Mockito.mock(InventoryService.class);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public RequestSerializationWrapper requestWrapper() {
            return new RequestSerializationWrapper();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private Vertx vertx;

    @Autowired
    private InventoryService inventoryService;

    @Autowired
    private RequestSerializationWrapper requestWrapper;

    @Autowired
    private ActionRequestHandler systemUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void registerConsumer_shouldRegisterVertxEventBusConsumer() {
        EventBus eventBusMock = Mockito.mock(EventBus.class);
        Mockito.when(vertx.eventBus()).thenReturn(eventBusMock);

        systemUnderTest.registerConsumer(null);

        Mockito.verify(eventBusMock.consumer(Matchers.anyString()), Mockito.times(1));
    }
}
```

However, this seems to try to resolve every dependency inside InventoryService instead of mocking the entire class. The above configuration gives me this error when I run:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private admin.messaging.converters.XmlToEntityConverter admin.persistence.service.InventoryService.entityConverter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [admin.messaging.converters.XmlToEntityConverter] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have also tried using a profile as suggested [here](http://www.baeldung.com/injecting-mocks-in-spring). The configuration class looks the same:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class ActionRequestHandlerTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Vertx vertx() {
        return Mockito.mock(Vertx.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public InventoryService inventoryService() {
        return Mockito.mock(InventoryService.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RequestSerializationWrapper requestWrapper() {
        return new RequestSerializationWrapper();
    }
}
```

The test is set up a bit differently with the following annotations instead:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ActionRequestHandler.class)
public class ActionRequestHandlerTest {
    // ...
}
```

But this instead gives me an error that Vertx can't be wired:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private io.vertx.core.Vertx admin.messaging.request.ActionRequestHandler.vertx; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [io.vertx.core.Vertx] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

How can I get this to work? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: upload `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` class.

Comment: Yes it does create a mock, but the fact that it is a mock doesn't suddenly erase all the metadata and annotations defined on the class. The `InventoryService` still has all the `@Autowired` fields that are still going to be detected by Spring, regardless of using a mock or not. To me it looks like you want to simply write a unit test whereas you are now trying to shoehorn an integration test into a unit test by using a full blown spring context. Don't use create an instance of the `ActionRequestHandler` yourself, inject the mocks, yourself and do the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need whole spring context to write **unit test** for `ActionRequestHandler`. You should use `MockitoJunitRunner` instead and do mocking on the dependencies.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class ActionRequestHandlerTest {

    @Mock
    private Vertx vertx;

    @Mock
    private InventoryService inventoryService;

    @Mock
    private RequestSerializationWrapper requestWrapper;

    @Mock
    private ProducerTemplate producer;

    @InjectMocks
    private ActionRequestHandler actionRequestHandler;

    @Test
    public void testRegisterConsumer() {
      .... Your code to test ActionRequestHandler#registerConsumer will go here....
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.toptal.com/java/a-guide-to-everyday-mockito).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need and now my tests run. I just overcomplicated things.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

This tells Junit to use the test-context.xml file in the same directory as your test. This file should be similar to the real context.xml you're using for spring, but pointing to test resources, naturally.